# Cannot retrieve option value from a add/remove list using php, jquery and html5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having trouble passing/displaying the values inside of a selected list.
I created a add/remove list using Jquery and I tried to display the values passed using foreach and for loops but it is still not working. The values I am trying to get are $existing_mID[$j] from the list named selectto. FYI, I am new to Javascript and therefore I have little understanding to the Jquery code below as I took different references and came up with it.

Please kindly let me know what should I do in order to get the values and I really appreciate your help.

Below is the function that I used to implement the add/remove function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $('#select-to option').attr('selected',true);
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$('#btn-remove').click(function(){
    $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
        $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $('#select-to option[value=' +$(this).val()+ ']').attr('selected',true);
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
});
```

And this is the form that I am using to set up the option attributes:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST"> 
<select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from" multiple="" size="10"> 
<?php $j=0; foreach($existing_mTitle as $item) { ;?>
<option value="<?php $existing_mID[$j];?>" > 
<?php echo "$existing_mID[$j] & $item";$j++;?> 
</option> <?php }?> 
</select> 
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a> 
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

<select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple="" size="10"> </select> 
<input type="submit" name="addArticle" value="Add" /> </form>
```

Below is how I tried to call the variables. They all don't work. So I am thinking if there is anything wrong with the Jquery code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['selectto']))
{
    $selected = $_POST['selectto'];
    echo "something in selected<br />";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($selected);$i++)
    echo "selected #1 : $selected[$i]";
    foreach ($selected as $item)
    echo "selected: item: $item";
    foreach ($selected as $idx => $item)
     {
     echo "selected: {$idx}: {$item}<br>\n";
 }
}
?>
```

Below is every line of my code that I am working on. I think that there is something wrong either with my option value attribute in my selectto list or my javascript. But I have no idea where to look for the errors. I apologize for posting a lot of codes but not much information given.

Please take a look at it and identify the reasons why the selectto option values are not displaying properly

```
$messagesql = "SELECT mID, mTITLE from test.message";
$mQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $messagesql) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));
$num_Mrows=mysqli_num_rows($mQuery);
echo "Number of message rows: $num_Mrows<br />";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mQuery,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $existing_mTitle[] = $row [ 'mTITLE' ];
    $existing_mID[] = $row ['mID'];
}

if(isset($_POST['selectto']))
{
    $selectedValues = '';
   foreach($_POST['selectto'] as $index => $value) {
       $selectedValues .= $value.', ';
   }
   $selectedValues = rtrim($selectedValues , ''); // remove last comma and whitespace
   echo 'The selected values are: '. $selectedValues ;  
   }


else
echo "nothing in selected<br />";

$articleSubmit = $_POST['addArticle'];
if(isset($articleSubmit))
{
    $titleSubmit = $_POST['articleTitle'];
    $summarySubmit = $_POST['articleSummary'];
    $abstractSubmit = $_POST['articleAbstract'];
    $regionSubmit = $_POST['articleRegion'];
    $populationSubmit = $_POST['articlePopulation'];
    $docTypeSubmit = $_POST['articleDocType'];
    $docStatusSubmit = $_POST['articleDocStatus'];
    $docYearSubmit = $_POST['articleDocYear'];
    $keywordSubmit = $_POST['articleKeyword'];

    if (null ==($titleSubmit) or null ==($summarySubmit) or null ==($abstractSubmit) or null ==($regionSubmit) or null ==($populationSubmit)
    or null ==($docTypeSubmit) or null ==($docStatusSubmit) or null ==($docYearSubmit) or null ==($keywordSubmit) /*or !isset($selected)*/)
    {
        echo "you need to fill in all the fields in order to add a new article.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "article submitted";
        $aSQL = "INSERT INTO test.article 
        (name, abstract, summary, region, population, docType, docStatus, docYear, keyword) values
        ('$titleSubmit', '$abstractSubmit', '$summarySubmit', '$regionSubmit', '$populationSubmit',
        '$docTypeSubmit', '$docStatusSubmit', '$docYearSubmit', '$keywordSubmit')";
        echo $aSQL;
        $aQuery = mysqli_query($dbc,$aSQL) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));

        $aidSQL = "SELECT aID from article where name = '$titleSubmit' and abstract = '$abstractSubmit' and summary = '$summarySubmit'";
        $aidQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $aidSQL) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($aidQuery, MYSQLI_BOTH))
        {
            $assocAID = $row;
        }
        echo "<br />assocAID: $assocAID[0]<br />";
        $selected = $_POST['selectto'];
        foreach($selected as $item)
        {
            $amSQL = "INSERT INTO a_m (assocAID, assocMID) values ($assocAID[0], $item)";
            $amQuery = mysqli_query($dbc,$amSQL) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));
        }
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test5-1-1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test5-1-1.css"/>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Add New Content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cyjm4.css"/>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Article</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Message</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Platform</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <p>Title:</p> <textarea name="articleTitle" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <p>Summary:</p> <textarea name="articleSummary" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
    <p>Abstract:</p> <textarea name="articleAbstract" cols="80" rows="6"></textarea>
    <p>Keyword:</p> <textarea name="articleKeyword" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>

    <div id="left">
    <p>Regions:</p>
    <select name="articleRegion">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="EUROPE">Europe</option>
    </select>
    <p>Populations:</p>
    <select name="articlePopulation">
        <option value="General">General</option>
        <option value="Elderly">Elderly</option>
        <option value="Women">Women</option>
    </select>
    <p>Document Type:</p>
    <select name="articleDocType">
        <option value="Research">Research</option>
        <option value="Report">Report</option>
    </select>
    <p>Document Status:</p>
    <select name="articleDocStatus">
        <option value="Published">Published</option>
        <option value="Unpublished">Unpublished</option>
    </select>
    <p>Documnet Year:</p>
    <select name="articleDocYear">
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    </div>

    <fieldset>

        <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from" multiple="" size="10">
        <?php $j=0; foreach($existing_mTitle as $item) { ;?>
            <option value=" <?php $existing_mID[$j]; ?> " ><?php echo "$existing_mID[$j] & $item";$j++;?></option>
        <?php }?>
        </select>

        <button type="button" id="btn-add">Add</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn-remove">Remove</button>
        <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple="" size="10">
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="addArticle" value="Add" />
</form>
 </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Title:</p> <textarea name="articleTilte" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <p>Summary:</p> <textarea name="articleSummary" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p></p>    
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` prints out?

Comment: (on a sidenote. Why use anchor tags to add/remove the elements. It would beter if u used `<button type="button" id="btn-add">Add</button>`. This way u don't need to hack out default anchor behavior)

Comment: print_r($_POST['selectto']) prints out 
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => ) when I select eight options.

Comment: I changed my anchor tags to a button as you suggested. Thanks for making my code simpler.

Comment: U are trying to foreach a string. The $_POST['selectto'] var will an array with all selected items. No need to do another foreach there then

Comment: I tried to set $selected = $_POST['selectto'] and echo $selected but there is still nothing though. How should I approach the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the code a bit for you as an example.
Lets say u have the following code

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from" multiple="" size="10"> 
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 10;$i++) {
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">Item '.$i.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select> 
    <button id="btn-add" type="button>Add &raquo;</a> 
    <button id="btn-remove" type="button">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple="" size="10"> </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="addArticle" value="Add" /> </form>
</form>

<?php
   print_r($_POST);
   /*
     Array
     (
         [selectto] => Array
         (
             [0] => 2
             [1] => 3
          )

         [addArticle] => Add
     )
   */
   //So this means that :
   $selectedValues = '';
   foreach($_POST['selectto'] as $index => $value) {
       $selectedValues .= $value.', ';
   }
   $selectedValues = rtrim($selectedValues , ', '); // remove last comma and whitespace
   echo 'The selected values are: '. $selectedValues ;    
?>
```

Comment: I have included that in my original code. Is there anything else I did wrong in my code?

Comment: Your example works perfectly when I created a new php and tested. that is exactly what I wanted, to get the results from selectto and display them properly.

Comment: However when I tried to implement that into my code. It is still displaying blanks. I have already posted my entire php code and please kindly take a look and let me know if you find any problem with it.

Comment: I got it! I made a silly mistake by not echoing inside my option attribute. <option value=" <?php ECHO "$existing_mID[$j]"; ?> did the trick

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me. really appreciated it.